# How can I make a Exception Serializable with a List<T> in it?

Tags: c#

```
[Serializable]
public struct Foo
{
    public string Info { get; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExceptionA : Exception
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get { return _foos; } }

    private List<Foo> _foos;
}
```

The C# compiler will complain that "Field _foos is a member of type ExceptionA which is serializable but is of type System.Collection.Generic.List which is not serializable"

How can I solve it? (Don't suppress CA2235, don't mark it as [NonSerialized])

Comment: Field _foos is a member of type ExceptionA which is serializable but is of type System.Collection.Generic.List<Foo> which is not serializable

Comment: Why do you want to serialize your private field?

Comment: I just want to make the custom Exception serializable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Serialize List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005900/how-to-serialize-listt)

Comment: You *do* need to mark the field as `[NonSerialized]` since the default mechanism simply won't apply, then use the appropriate attributes for [custom serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization) to serialize it yourself (by converting to/from an array, most likely, as those are serializable). Note that it's increasingly less relevant to actually have serializable exceptions, despite what code checkers may say -- unless you're actively using AppDomains, there's little need to bother.